# How to return a value from axios outside axios function

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have a router.get which calls another function, like this:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const data = especiaisTest.getEspeciais();
  console.log(data);
});
```

The function which is calling is this one:

```
function getEspeciais() {
  db.query(async (tokenResponse) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(URL, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenResponse.accessToken}`,
        },
      });

      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  });
}
```

Whenever i call it, I just get console.logged an undefined.

I tried returning a value outside the *db.query* function, for example:

```
function getEspeciais() {
  db.query(async (tokenResponse) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(URL, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenResponse.accessToken}`,
        },
      });

      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
      });
      return 'hello'
    }
```

And it will display the 'hello' in the console. How can I get the response.data out of the db.query in order to be able to show the data?

Comment: I think you should do ``return db.query ...`` in your `getEspeciais` function

Comment: @A.Anvarbekov I tried that and still getting undefined

Comment: Are you returning both `return response.data` and `return db.query`? Also try putting `await` before returns

Answer (score 0):

Question codes.

```js
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const data = especiaisTest.getEspeciais();
  console.log(data);
});


function getEspeciais() {
  db.query(async (tokenResponse) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(URL, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenResponse.accessToken}`,
        },
      });

      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  });
}
```

Should be:

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const data = await especiaisTest.getEspeciais();
```

```
async function getEspeciais() {
  return db.query(async (tokenResponse) => {
```

Then you will see something else rather than undefined.
If return undefined, the ***db.query*** method return nothing.

Comment: didn't work, if I put the a console.log() before return response.data , I get the undefined but after a bit I get the console.log from above

Comment: @JoseBernardo Oh, I miss read on code, I will update answer.